# Can´t change submenu style

Tags: html, css

I need to align my submenu to the left with some margin and remove the border from the right side... but if I remove it, the border in the menu is also removed and I don't want this...

```
<nav>
    <ul class="fancyNav">
        <li id="quemsomos" class="menlog"><a href="index.php"><img src="imgs/Logo.png"  width="37" height="45" /></a>
        </li>
        <li id="quemsomos"><a href="quemsomos.php?web=1"><font face="din" size="4">QUEM SOMOS</font></a>
            <!--start of sub menu-->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">link the zone 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">link2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">l for example</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--end of sub menu-->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RHCn7/2/

Comment: can you elaborate what is the exact issue?

Comment: i need change the submenu style, align text to the left and remove that border from right...

Comment: But what is the issue when you remove it?

Comment: The same issue asked 5 minutes before

Comment: Deekey you are wrong... this a new issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add padding

```
ul li ul {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #D5D5D7;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/RHCn7/6/

Comment: @Ricardo You are asking the same second times

Comment: Thanks man... can you tell me how put the mouseover effect for all area like a block... as you can see when he do mouseover only the word of the item have background... i need all block have background, the left to the righ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RHCn7/5/)

```
#quemsomos ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#quemsomos ul li {
    border: none;
}
```

### **EDIT**(answer to the request in the comment):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RHCn7/10/)

```
#quemsomos ul li {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man... can you tell me how put the mouseover effect for all area like a block... as you can see when he do mouseover only the word of the item have background... i need all block have background, the left to the righ... thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks Beniamin great code... only last thing, as you can see in submenu when you do mouse over you see two lines one on the left and one on the right like a border or someting... can remove that?